# Spark DStream periodically call saveAsObjectFile using transform does not work as expected

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, hdfs, apache-kafka

I read data from Kafka using `DirectKafkaStream` API [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgB9h.png), do some transformations, updating a count then writing data back to Kafka. Actually this peace of code is in a test:

```
kafkaStream[Key, Value]("test")
      .map(record => (record.key(), 1))
      .updateStateByKey[Int](
        (numbers: Seq[Int], state: Option[Int]) =>
          state match {
            case Some(s) => Some(s + numbers.length)
            case _ => Some(numbers.length)
          }
      )
      .checkpoint(this)("count") {
        case (save: (Key, Int), current: (Key, Int)) =>
          (save._1, save._2 + current._2)
      }
      .map(_._2)
      .reduce(_ + _)
      .map(count => (new Key, new Result[Long](count.toLong)))
      .toKafka(Key.Serializer.getClass.getName, Result.longKafkaSerializer.getClass.getName)
```

The `checkpoint` operator is an enrichment to the `DStream` API I've created, which should practically save one RDD of the given `DStream` of one `Time` into HDFS using `saveAsObjectFile`. Practically it saves the result of every 60th micro-batch (RDD) into HDFS.

Checkpoint does the following:

```
def checkpoint(processor: Streaming)(name: String)(
mergeStates: (T, T) => T): DStream[T] = {
val path = processor.configuration.get[String](
  "processing.spark.streaming.checkpoint-directory-prefix") + "/" +
  Reflection.canonical(processor.getClass) + "/" + name + "/"
logInfo(s"Checkpoint base path is [$path].")

processor.registerOperator(name)

if (processor.fromCheckpoint && processor.restorationPoint.isDefined) {
  val restorePath = path + processor.restorationPoint.get.ID.stringify
  logInfo(s"Restoring from path [$restorePath].")
  checkpointData = context.objectFile[T](restorePath).cache()

  stream
    .transform((rdd: RDD[T], time: Time) => {
      val merged = rdd
        .union(checkpointData)
        .map[(Boolean, T)](record => (true, record))
        .reduceByKey(mergeStates)
        .map[T](_._2)

      processor.maybeCheckpoint(name, merged, time)

      merged
    }
  )
} else {
  stream
    .transform((rdd: RDD[T], time: Time) => {
      processor.maybeCheckpoint(name, rdd, time)

      rdd
    })
}
}
```

The effective piece of code is the following:

```
dstream.transform((rdd: RDD[T], time: Time) => {
      processor.maybeCheckpoint(name, rdd, time)

      rdd
    })
```

Where `dstream` variable in the above code is the result of the previous operator, which is `updateStateByKey`, so a transform is called right after `updateStateByKey`.

```
def maybeCheckpoint(name: String, rdd: RDD[_], time: Time) = {
  if (doCheckpoint(time)) {
    logInfo(s"Checkpointing for operator [$name] with RDD ID of [${rdd.id}].")
    val newPath = configuration.get[String](
    "processing.spark.streaming.checkpoint-directory-prefix") + "/" +
    Reflection.canonical(this.getClass) + "/" + name + "/" + checkpointBarcode
    logInfo(s"Saving new checkpoint to [$newPath].")
    rdd.saveAsObjectFile(newPath)
    registerCheckpoint(name, Operator(name), time)
    logInfo(s"Checkpoint completed for operator [$name].")
  }
}
```

As you see most of the code is just bookkeeping, but a `saveAsObjectFile` is called effectively.

The problem is that even that the resulting RDDs from `updateStateByKey` should be persisted automatically, when `saveAsObjectFile` is called on every Xth micro-batch, Spark will recompute everything, from the scratch, from the beginning of the streaming job, starting off by reading everything from Kafka again. I've tried to put and force `cache` or `persist` with different levels of storage, on the DStreams as well as on the RDDs.

Micro-batches:

[image: Micro batches]

DAG for job 22:

[image: DAG for job 22]

DAG for job that runs `saveAsObjectFile`:

[image: SAOF1]
[image: SAOF2]

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgB9h.png) Using Spark 2.1.0.

Comment: It's not that `saveAsObjectFile` is the bad boy here, a simple `count` does the same thing,

Comment: By calling `saveAsObjectFile` you tell spark to execute an action, which executes all transformations defined on the initial stream (remember: transformations are lazy). When you execute other actions afterwards (for example `reduce`) the same transformations are executed again. To prevent that you could call `dstream.cache()` just before the first action (i.e., `checkpoint(this)(...)`)

Comment: @AdiGerber I have tried that of course. Just before `checkpoint` enrichment, cached and even tried a persist with disk storage, to be sure that memory-only storage levels are not going to force RDDs to be evicted. Anyways, I'd only "reuse" the last cached RDD, which would only be 4KB in size - test with small amount of data - 300.000 key-value records with a cardinality of 10. 10 keys are stored by `updateStateByKey` actually.

Comment: Please can you post the `checkpoint` function signature, and, ideally, the body?

Comment: @ImDarrenG Thanks for asking, I've added it.

Comment: If possible, please can you add a screenshot of the DAG from the spark ui?

Comment: @ImDarrenG Added DAGs.

Comment: I've found the solution to this problem. Not trivial, but can be guessed based on the information I've provided. It is actually more than what anyone would need to figure it out. I'll leave the bounty here until the end, just in case someone would provide the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe using `transform` to periodically checkpoint will cause unexpected cache behaviour.

Instead using `foreachRDD` to perform periodic checkpointing will allow the DAG to remain stable enough to effectively cache RDDs.

I'm almost positive that was the solution to a similar issue we had a while ago.

Comment: Checkpointing cuts the linage graph (when you call it on a DStream), but still not going to help me here. The problem was not the fact that the linage graph was wide. `updateStateByKey` creates a `StateDStream`, and when you look into it, you'll find it is persisted into memory by default, in fact each RDD is persisted into memory. Effectively, what I do there, is that I call a `count` on such an RDD, that should be pulled from the BlockManager by the cached RDD ID, instead of recomputing it. I'll try out your solution, just in case, but I don't think it will help me.

Comment: Please do, and let us know, it's a good idea to eliminate the low-hanging fruit! :)

Comment: Having said that, I think you are right. The annoying thing is I'm certain I've seen a very similar issue before but can't remember how we solved it.

Comment: I have `ssc.checkpoint` set up, since Spark forces `checkpoint` directory to be set when `updateStateByKey` or similar "flatMap with state" operator is used. If you want to force the job generation to be started without `ssc.checkpoint`, the checkpointing must be turned off explicitly for `updateStateByKey`. Anyway, I've set up a manual Spark `checkpoint` and `localCheckpoint` right after `updateStateByKey`. No use as expected.

Comment: Another hint. Tried `mapWithState` as well, same symptoms.

Comment: You've hit the correct answer. `foreachRDD` must be used, since `transform` will not handle cached RDDs correctly. Could you improve your answer to be based on this matter?

Comment: Glad we found the issue. Have edited answer accordingly.